# Fetch multiple documents in a stored procedure (Azure DocumentDB)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two document types, Listing and Products. A Listing object contains a list of Products for certain countries, like this:

**Listing**:

```
{
  "Name": "Default",
  "Countries": {
    "_default": [
      "4QlxAPFcCAAPAAAAAAAAAA==",
      "4QlxAPFcCAAHAAAAAAAAAA=="
    ],
    "US": [
      "4QlxAPFcCAAIAAAAAAAAAA==",
      "4QlxAPFcCAAHAAAAAAAAAA=="
    ]
  },
  "Type": "Listing",
  "id": "dfed1839-07c5-482b-81c5-669b1dbcd0b6",
  "_rid": "4QlxAPFcCAAEAAAAAAAAAA=="
}
```

**Product:**

```
{
    "Name": "Widget",
    "Price": 3.45,
    "Type": "Product",
    "_rid": "4QlxAPFcCAAHAAAAAAAAAA=="
}
```

My goal was to create a *stored procedure* in the Azure DocumentDB collection taking two parameters, `rid`and `country`, which would essentially fetch the Listing document, and the documents for that country, in the most efficient manner possible. My presumption is that loading a Document by its resource Id using `getContext().getCollection().readDocument(...)` would be the fastest way, thus attempting to create a stored procedure for this.

My attempts have been to nest the consecutive calls (callback hell?), using generator/iterators with yield and then with a pure `Promise` approach. All of the attempts have given the same result:

It will fetch the first document, but will end quite abruptly after the document has been received.

For reference, here's my latest attempt:

```
function test(rid, country) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionSelfLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var docsLink = collectionSelfLink + "docs/";
    var body = getContext().getResponse().setBody;  

    function getDocument(rid) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var accepted = collection.readDocument(docsLink + rid, (err, doc, opts) => {
                resolve(doc);
            });

            if (!accepted)
                reject("Not accepted");            
        });
    }

    getDocument(rid)
        .then(doc => { 
            body("0. First step"); // set test body 

            // Countries is a Dictionary<string, string[]> with resource ids
            return doc.Countries[country] || doc.Countries["_default"];
        })
        // This is how far it gets, resulting in response "1. Documents to fetch: 2"
        .then(a => body("1. Documents to fetch: " + a.length))
        .then(a => a.map(function(productId) { return getDoument(productId); }))
        .then(a => body("2. It should come this far, right?"))
        .then(a => Promise.all(a))
        .then(a => body(a))
        .catch(function(e) { throw new Error(JSON.stringify(e)); });
}
```

Comment: I'm not a promises expert. I tend to hand code my callbacks or use async.js (yes, you can load it as a dependency inside a sproc), but I wonder if your problem is in the line that calls `a.map`. The wrapping `.then` will return a promise, which is an array of promises from that point forward.

Also, you have a preference for single line functions in your `.then()` calls but some of those things (calls to body and even call to .map could be done in line. The only thing you really need a promise for is the async call to readDocument. On the other hand this may just be a promise coding style.

Comment: I tried the above call chain in a REPL with a mocked `getDocument` function, and it works. I have also, as noted, tried doing for loop inside an initial `collection.readDocument(...)`, and when using a for-of/for-in/for it will terminate half-way-through (taking 2 out of 4 elements I had in the list). When using a `.forEach`, it went through the entire array, but didn't wait until the calls were done. I'm curious on how the caller determines when to 'terminate'...

Comment: How big is the array? How does a fanned out (`a.map()`) promise chain decide how much parallelization to implement? My new theory is that with a for loop or your a.map promises approach, you fan out too wide and exceed some resource. You may need to limit the parallelization like async.js' `...Limit()` methods.

Comment: It's been a couple of days with no answer here. What's the current status?

Comment: I've posted a proposed answer to my question, as the Promise just did not work whatsoever. @LarryMaccherone, the amount of documents that was fetched was merely between 2 and 4, so the degree of parallelism wasn't in any means high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that nesting the calls **do** in fact work, if you alter the response body frequently(?)

The following procedure worked as expected:

```
function test(rid, country) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionSelfLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var docsLink = collectionSelfLink + "docs/";
    var body = getContext().getResponse().setBody;

    var accepted = collection.readDocument(docsLink + rid, (err, doc, opts) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err.message);

        // Countries is a Dictionary<string, string[]> with resource ids
        var offerIds = doc.Countries[country] || doc.Countries["_default"];
        var result = [];

        for (var docId of offerIds) {
            var subAccepted =
                collection.readDocument(docsLink + docId, (err, doc, opts) => {
                    if (err) throw new Error(err.message);

                    result.push(doc);
                });

            if (!subAccepted)
                throw new Error("A subsequent request was not accepted");

            body(result); // <-- Note, setting body in each iteration.
        }
    });

    if (!accepted)
        throw new Error("The request was not accepted");
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this wasn't as performant as I expected. Doing similar queries from the client was even *faster*!